# Replacing HTML content without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML content like this:

```
some of the string content <font color=blue>Test content <BR><BR><BR>
   <DIV  id='idOfTheDiv'>
     some more goes here
     <P>Test Content</P>
   </DIV>
  </font>
```

I want to remove the div without removing it's content, so the resultant data should look like

```
some of the string content `<font color=blue>Test content <BR><BR><BR>`
       some more goes here


         <P>Test Content</P>
      </font>
```

Please note that i do not want to remove the content of the div, also i do not want to add any unwanted HTML element just to remove the div. I have tried various techniques but none of them is working at the moment.

I tried this replacing the innerHTML but it did'nt worked. I can not use replaceChild, as

```
<DIV  id='idOfTheDiv'>
     some more goes here
     <P>Test Content</P>
   </DIV>
```

is a combonation of text plus HTML so CreateTextNode does'nt workks here as it changes all HTML to plain text.

Please suggest. Thanks a Ton..

Answer (score 1):

- Loop over the elements inside the div (use [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) as it also includes text nodes, while `children` does not).
- Place the elements one-by-one before the div using [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- Remove the div using [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
var el = document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv');

while (el.childNodes.length) {
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.childNodes[0], el);
}
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VG5ZF/

`el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.childNodes[0], el);` moves the first child node outside from element, reducing the length of `childNodes` NodeList. So in every iteration `el.childNodes[0]` is going to be next one. Until there are childs.